# Soap Webservice Programming, wsdl created but can't access from browser

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

i'm trying to make a SOAP Webservice but I can't access my wsdl through web browser file after creating it. I get the 404 error for some reason. I also did a client for my web service but it can't access the wsdl files as well.

I use:
Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 
Tomcat 7.0
Apache CXF 2.0

I have 2 wsdl files in my wsdl folder, but i should have just one.

here are they:

**calimpl.wsdl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="CalimplService" targetNamespace="http://webservice.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="com.webservice" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:import namespace="com.webservice" location="Ical.wsdl">
    </wsdl:import>
  <wsdl:binding name="CalimplServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:Ical">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="rech">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Rech" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="rech">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="rechResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="CalimplService">
    <wsdl:port name="CalimplPort" binding="tns:CalimplServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Calcu/services/CalimplPort"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Ical.wsdl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Ical" targetNamespace="com.webservice" xmlns:ns1="com.webservice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="com.webservice" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="com.webservice" version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="rech" type="tns:rech"/>

  <xs:element name="rechResponse" type="tns:rechResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="rech">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="rechResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="rechResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns1:rechResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="rech">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns1:rech">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="Ical">
    <wsdl:operation name="rech">
      <wsdl:input name="rech" message="ns1:rech">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="rechResponse" message="ns1:rechResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

do you have any idea for my problem ?

Comment: Is ICal an interface or an implementation? Share the code to review and assist further.

Comment: package com.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public interface Ical {

 public int rech(int x, int y);
}

Comment: package com.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.webservice.Ical")
public class Calimpl implements Ical {

 @Override
 public int rech(int x, int y) {
  int z = x - y;
  return z;
 }

}

Comment: yeah Ical is an Interface

Comment: And how are you generating the WSDL? Through wsdl plugin for maven or using wsdl2java cli tool for CXF?

Comment: Also, your first WSDL Ical.wsdl looks like an abstract WSDL.
And calimpl.wsdl is concrete WSDL
You should be able to access service at your endpoint http://localhost:8080/Calcu/services/CalimplPort

Comment: yeah, right click on Implementation -> create web service -> and then with cxf 2.x. and tomcat 7

Comment: oh and i added to Calimpl @WebService() the targetNamespace="com.webservice"

Comment: if i don't add the targetNamespace i ll get an Error

Comment: yeah i know but i can't, and my client program neither

Comment: can it be that my server causes the problem ?

Comment: because with javax rs (without apache cxf) it just works fine